# How to edit Magento 2 Database Configuration file

Tags: magento2, error, change-password

i have changed the password of database in the server. then, i get error message for front store  and admin panel of magento. how can i solve it ? immediately , please.

front store: 
**"There has been an error processing your request**

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

```
Error log record number: 1429988333864"
```

admin: 
"There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

```
Error log record number: 1030432780141
```

Comment: for future requests -> get into the var/log/reports folder of your magento 2 installation and check the corresponding file (the log record number is the filename) for the real error message. that will at least make for a much clearer question that helps others to find suitable answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `app/etc/env.php` then update this:

```
'db' =>
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'database_name',
        'username' => 'database_username',
        'password' => 'database_password',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `app/etc/local.xml` and set your new password here too:

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        ...
        <username><![CDATA[your_user]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[your_password]]></password>
        ...
```

Comment: no local.xml file

Comment: @Amd2030 Magento1 or 2?

Comment: `app/etc/local.xml` is for Magento 1. Correct are answers with `app/etc/env.php`.

Comment: @pevik the question was edited after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it from `/Magento/app/etc/env.php`

See [How to edit Magento 2 Database Configuration file?](https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-edit-magento-2-database-configuration-file/)